# Apache Beam Count Rows and store in a variable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-beam

I'm trying to count the number of elements in a PCollection and store it in a variable which I want to use it for further calculations. Any guidance on how I can do it?

```
import apache_beam as beam

pipeline =  beam.Pipeline()
total_elements = (
    pipeline
    | 'Create elements' >> beam.Create(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'])
    | 'Count all elements' >> beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
    | beam.Map(print))

print(total_elements + 10)

pipeline.run()
```

Printing the total_elements works, but my requirement is to add an integer to it.
I tried using int(total_elements) and that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `beam.pvalue.AsSingleton` transform

```
import apache_beam as beam

pipeline =  beam.Pipeline()
total_elements = (
    pipeline
    | 'Create elements' >> beam.Create(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'])
    | 'Count all elements' >> beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
    | beam.pvalue.AsSingleton())

# This will print the total number of elements in the PCollection, plus 10.
print(total_elements + 10)

pipeline.run()
```

Note that the `beam.pvalue.AsSingleton` transform will only work if the input PCollection contains exactly one value. If the input PCollection is empty or contains more than one value, this transform will raise an error.

Comment: I get an error when I tried the code. `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pcoll'`

Answer (score -2):

```
import apache_beam as beam

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  total_elements = (
      pipeline
      | 'Create plants' >> beam.Create(
          ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
      | 'Count all elements' >> beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
      | beam.Map(print))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).